# Check login and redirect in Codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

I have a problem when use check_login function.
When I enter http://localhost/home/ and put admin password, it does not redirect to home admin page. But when I try to http://localhost/home/control/lampu. It still redirect to login page.

```
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('loginModel');
        $this->load->model('pengaturanModel');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("toastr.error('", "','');"); 
    }

    public function index()
    {  
        if($this->session->userdata('id_pengaturan')){
            redirect('control/lampu');
        }

        $data['pesan'] = '';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('kodeakses', 'Kode Akses Keamanan', 'trim|required|md5');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {

        }
        else
        {   
            $data['pesan'] = "toastr.error('Kode Akses Keamanan Tidak Boleh Kosong!','')";

            $check = $this->loginModel->get_records($this->input->post('kodeakses'));

            if($check){
                foreach ($check as $row) {
                    $login = array(
                        'id_pengaturan'  => $row->id,
                    );

                    $this->session->set_userdata($login);

                    redirect('control/lampu');
                }
            }else{
                $data['pesan'] = "toastr.error('Kode Akses Keamanan Salah!','')";
            }

        }

        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    }

}
```

And this code loginmodels

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LoginModel extends CI_Model {

    function get_records($kodeakses){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('pengaturan', array('kode_akses'=> $kodeakses), 1);

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function getKode($kodeakses){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('pengaturan', array('kode_akses'=> $kodeakses), 1);

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

}

/* End of file login_m.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/login_m.php */
```

Comment: home controller content?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `num_rows()` is not a part of query builder functions. You can try to use this to count your result:

```
$this->db->count_all_results()
```

Refer to - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results

If this solves your answer, please mark this as answer. Thanks!

Comment: OP is not using $this->db->num_rows(), they are using it correctly on the query result object

Comment: Yep that works on the query result object but he's using the the **query builder** object - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results

Comment: @vickel, I won't mind if you point me on the right direction here, just edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: difficult to say, as OP's get_records() might return more than 1 result, which then returns false again

Comment: Yeah that's his logic, we can't conclude unless he answers us :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

$row = $query->row();

if (isset($row))
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

Comment: `affected_rows()` won't give result because there are no insert or update statement involved. He basically just wants to count a result from a select statement.